# Создание переменной или new

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
//способ 1    
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("somefile");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

//способ 2
BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile"));
```

В обоих случаях я получу желаем результат.

Какой из этих двух способов предпочтительней и почему?

Стоит ли не создавая переменную писать сразу `new SomeVar()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле оба варианты одинаковы, по тому что, компилятор оптимизирует код по своему усмотрению.

Я рекомендую использовать 1 способ, т.к. он более удобный при отладке.

Answer (score 5):

Хоть эти способы и одинаковы, но все заключается в необходимости элемента в дальнейшем, если он нужен только для конструктура класса, то, конечно, не держите его в памяти, но если использывание в дальнейшем нужно - сохраняй.
И заполни правило: между памятью и вычислительными ресурсами - жертвуй памятью. Конечно, если задача не состоит в економии самой памяти.

Comment: Особенно это правило верно для мощных микроконтроллеров с килобайтом памяти на борту. ;-) Или для сортировки терабайта-другого данных. Каждое правило верно только при ограничениях на область его использования.